# List of lists in python

Tags: python

If I am given two list of lists such as follows:

```
list1 = [['John',2],
         ['Smith',5],
         ['Kapil',3]]

list2 = [['Smith',2],
         ['John',2],
         ['Stephen',3]]
```

I want a list as follows:

```
final = [['John',4],
        ['Smith',7],
        ['Kapil',3],
        ['Stephen',3]]
```

which will contain the sum of the numbers if the name has occurred in both list1 and list2.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33929441/2572645

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple way to do this is to use a dictionary. Something like this:

```
list1 = [['John',2],['Smith',5],['Kapil',3]]

list2 = [['Smith',2],['John',2],['Stephen',3]]

dict = {}

for item in list1:
    try:
        dict[item[0]] += item[1]
    except:
        dict[item[0]] = item[1]

for item in list2:
    try:
        dict[item[0]] += item[1]
    except:
        dict[item[0]] = item[1]

print dict
```

This gives the output:

```
{'John': 4, 'Smith': 7, 'Kapil': 3, 'Stephen': 3}
```

Then turn it into a list of lists, with the following:

```
results = []
for k, v in dict.items():
    results.append([k, v])

print results
# [['John', 4], ['Smith', 7], ['Kapil', 3], ['Stephen', 3]]
```

Here's a reusable function for multiple lists:

```
list1 = [['John',2],['Smith',5],['Kapil',3]]
list2 = [['Smith',2],['John',2],['Stephen',3]]
list3 = [['Smith',7],['John',5],['Kapil',33]]

def sort_lists(*args):
    dict = {}
    for arg in args:
        for item in arg:
            try:
                dict[item[0]] += item[1]
            except:
                dict[item[0]] = item[1]
    results = []
    for k, v in dict.items():
        results.append([k, v])

    return results

print sort_lists(list1, list2, list3)
```

Comment: Or use `list(final.items())` to convert it to a list of tuples