# How to convert the second element of a tuple from string to float in Python?

Tags: python, tuples

I'm learning Python and I have extracted this out of a `.txt` file using `split(";")`:

```
[(86246, '7.5'), (86246, '1.5'), (86246, '5.9'), (86246, '1.9'), (86246, '10.3'), (86246, '7.')]
```

I would like to get the following result:

```
[(86246, 7.5), (86246, 1.5), (86246, 5.9), (86246, 1.9), (86246, 10.3), (86246, 7.)]
```

The goal is to obtain float values rather than strings to then make a dictionary out of [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33929389).

Answer (score 2):

You could try using [list comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```py
>>> list = [(86246, '7.5'), (86246, '1.5'), (86246, '5.9'), (86246, '1.9'), (86246, '10.3'), (86246, '7.')]
>>> [(t[0], float(t[1])) for t in list]
[(86246, 7.5), (86246, 1.5), (86246, 5.9), (86246, 1.9), (86246, 10.3), (86246, 7.0)]
```

Comment: I am getting this error:                                                                                                        [(t[0], float(t[1])) for t in my_list]
        ^^^^^^
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: Could you share how my_list looks like? Please make sure that the second element of each tuple does not contain an invalid decimal separator (for instance 4,5 instead of 4.5).

Comment: No need, one of my string element was empty. It's all fixed now thx!

Comment: @Delta23 how did you fix it?  It's probably easier than you think: `float(t[1] or '0')`.